# Large program analysis with soot+paddle

Tags: java, soot

I am trying to use Soot's paddle framework to do context sensitive "points to" analysis for android apps having 20KLOC-50KLOC of Java code. I have modified soot to have multiple entry points as apps don't have a main method. When I run the analysis it throws following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Value 65543 was too large in      domain soot.jimple.paddle.bdddomains.MethodDomain!
at jedd.internal.Domain.setBits(Domain.java:62)
at jedd.internal.Jedd.literal(Jedd.java:158)
```

I increased the value 14 in SigDomain(14) in  SigDomain.jedd file in paddle source code which  caused the analysis to run much longer but still at the end it failed giving the same exception. (I have also increased the stack size and heap size of jvm to 1 and 4 GB).
If I set this value SigDomain(14) too large like ~20000 the paddle analysis doesn't even start.

I have following options for paddle:

```
    opt.put("verbose","true");
    opt.put("bdd","true");
    opt.put("backend","javabdd");
    opt.put("context","kcfa");
    opt.put("k","2");
    opt.put("propagator","auto");
    opt.put("conf","ofcg");
    opt.put("order","32");
    opt.put("q","auto");
    opt.put("set-impl","double");
    opt.put("double-set-old","hybrid");
    opt.put("double-set-new","hybrid");
    opt.put("pre-jimplify","false");


    PaddleTransformer pt = new PaddleTransformer();
    PaddleOptions paddle_opt = new PaddleOptions(opt);
    pt.setup(paddle_opt);
    pt.solve(paddle_opt);
    soot.jimple.paddle.Results.v().makeStandardSootResults();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the maintainers of Soot let me advise you that you'll usually get faster help on the Soot mailing list, as not all of us might be watching StackOverflow. Ondrej Lhotak might be able to help with this...

Context-sensitive analysis is generally very expensive. Possible solution are (1) to do a demand-driven context-sensitive analysis (which Soot supports too; check the command line options), (2) construct you own hand-crafted pointer abstraction, or (3) exclude some of the runtime library from analysis (which would be unsound). Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric. I will go ahead and set "cs-demand" to true for demand driven analysis. I sent mail to soot-list some 2 days back before posting to stack-overflow but it is still waiting for moderator approval.

Comment: Hi. I am not clear about what you mean. The soot list is not usually moderated...

Comment: I got this email after I sent my question as email to soot-list@sable.mcgill.ca.                                            Your mail to 'Soot-list' with the subject

    "using paddle for large program analysis"

Is being held until the list moderator can review it for approval.

The reason it is being held:

    Post by non-member to a members-only list

Either the message will get posted to the list, or you will receive
notification of the moderator's decision.  If you would like to cancel
this posting, please visit the following URL: and after that I got no e-mail.